# Windows XP firewall doesnot allow to connect from vpn

Tags: networking, windows-xp, vpn, openvpn

I connect to my home asus router through openvpn. I can use internet over vpn but i cannot see Windows XP computers in the home network.

I asked similar question for Windows 7 
[Windows firewall doesnot allow to connect from vpn](https://superuser.com/questions/1106907/windows-firewall-doesnot-allow-to-connect-from-vpn)

I got the answer that i should change firewall settings. I did it and i can see Win7.

Unfortunately the same recipe doesn't work for Windows Xp.

Addresses in local network have form 192.168.1.x

For openvpn client the router creates virtual network 10.8.0.x

Could anyone help me to set the firewall in WinXp?